# Why can't I access my administration interface?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, admin

I'm working through the projects in the book "PHP and MySQL Web Development 4th Edition" and I keep getting an error when I load up the Chapter 28 files using the CD-ROM provided.

The chapter is on building a Shopping Cart tool using books stored in a MySQL database. The files on the CD-ROM contain the completed project, so I imported the SQL files and implemented the MySQL database so I could follow along with the project. However, I'm having trouble accessing the administration interface.  The file "login.php" is the page where the admin can log in and add, edit or delete books from the list of available books to add to your shopping cart. Yet I get some errors when I open the "login.php" file in my browser. It looks the same as the screenshot in the textbook, except at the top of my screen I get:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmysql4e\Chapter28\output_fns.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: total_price in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmysql4e\Chapter28\output_fns.php on line 10
```

There can't be any errors with the code, since this is the code that was in the CD-ROM files. 
Lines 6-12 of output_fns.php looks like this:

```
// declare the session variables we want access to inside the function
if (!$_SESSION['items']) {
  $_SESSION['items'] = '0';
}
if (!$_SESSION['total_price']) {
  $_SESSION['total_price'] = '0.00';
}
```

Now the errors do go away if I add in 
    session_start();
at the top of the page, but this can't be right. Surely there is no code editing necessary since these are the files contained on the CD-ROM.

Even when I edit the code to rid the errors, I'm also having trouble being able to log in to the interface.

The chapter goes on to display screenshots of every page of the Shopping Cart after an admin logs in. Except I can't seem to be able to successfully log in, so I'm not able to see these screenshots on my browser. After importing the SQL files, there is a table called "admin" in the database that was created. In "admin", there is a username and password column, with one default admin already registered ("admin" as the username, and a long random password as the password). When I enter this information in "login.php", it does not work. When I edit the "admin" table to add a new admin user, it still does not work. I must not be connecting to my database correctly, right? The pages are definitely displaying information from my database, but for some reason the browser is having trouble talking to the DB when I try to log in as an admin.

It seems there should be no errors with the coding since I'm just using the files provided with the CD-ROM. There has to be some simple error that I'm completely overlooking... right?

Thanks for reading and any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if more information is necessary.

Comment: maybe you missing isset. so the code looks like !isset($_SESSION['items'])

Comment: Do you see a `session_start();` somewhere before those lines of code?

Comment: Search your whole project for a `session_start()` - it won't work without that. Either there are mistakes in the supplied files, or you've not included the file that starts the session system.

Comment: I'm able to rid the errors with the "isset", however I still can't log in to the interface. Where can I find or change the login information? The book doesn't seem to explain this

Answer (score 0):

try these one :

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['items'])) {
  $_SESSION['items'] = '0';
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['total_price'])) {
  $_SESSION['total_price'] = '0.00';
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Any ideas as to how I would access the admin interface? I'm not able to enter in the correct log in information; I'm not sure where to find or how to change this information

Answer (score 0):

The username and password for this project is
"admin".
I was only able to figure this out by guessing; I don't see this information anywhere in the textbook.

If I use the "isset" method you guys provided, the 2 errors do disappear from "login.php" page, however it doesn't seem to successfully log me in when I enter the password. Whenever I visit a link, I get an error message saying that I'm not logged in as admin and am not authorized to view the content.

However when I ignore the 2 errors on "login.php" and just type in the username and password, I am able to successfully log in and add, delete and edit the shopping cart.

I'm confused, but am pleased to have made some progress with this whole thing. Thanks a lot for all who have helped. My mission now is to figure out how to get rid of these errors at the top of the page, and also be able to successfully log in as admin.